# Cómo añado elementos a un arreglo conforme el usuario va ingresando numeros hasta que ingresa una letra

Tags: array, c

Quiero crear un programa en C que dado algunos números ingresados por el usuario, obtenga el valor máximo, su posición y aparte sume todos los valores. El usuario puede ingresar cuantos números quiera de la siguiente manera: ingresa un número, da enter, ingresa otro. El programa continúa pidiendo números hasta que el usuario ingrese "x".

Hasta ahora estaba pensando en pedir los números al usuario y almacenarlos en un array, para después obtener lo que me pide. Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora y me sale error, por favor ayúdenme :/

```
#include <stdio.h>

void agregarElemento(int c[], int size_agrega, int element_Agregar);

int main() {

    int n = 1; //tamaño del arreglo
    int array[n]; //define el arreglo
    int i; //primer elemento del arreglo
    scanf("%d", &i);
    array[0] = i;

    //Mientras el usuario ingrese cualquier número, menos la "x", se agrega ese número al arreglo
    while (i != "x") {
        n++;
        agregarElemento(array, n, i);
    }

    //se obtiene el número máximo y su posición
    int mayor = array[0];
    int posMayor = 0;

    for(j=1;j<n;j++){
        if(array[j]>mayor){
            mayor=array[j];
            posMayor = j;
        }
    }

    //Se hace la suma de todos los elementos del arreglo
    int sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }

    printf("max: ", mayor);
    printf("pos: ", posMayor);
    printf("sum:", sum);


    return 0;
}    

//metodo para agregar un elemento al arreglo
void agregarElemento(int c[], int size_agrega, int element_Agregar)
{
    int j;

    size_agrega++;
    c[size_agrega] = element_Agregar;
}
```

Sé que está mal la parte de while (i != "x") porque i es un entero, pero no sé cómo hacer la parte de que siga pidiendo números hasta que ponga "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los VLA (Variable length Arrays) fueron introducidos en el estándar de C a partir de C99, el problema de esta característica, es que no se puede redimensionar la memoria, debido a que, se aloja en la pila. El problema radica que si te interesa tener un código portable para otros compiladores, como por ejemplo, `cl.exe` (de Visual Studio), no se recomienda su uso, adicionalmente, no hay ninguna razón de usarlo, porqué para eso tenemos funciones como `malloc` y `realloc` para gestionar la memoria dinámica. Si usas VLA, no podrás detectar si hubo un error en la asignación de memoria, con `malloc` y `realloc` si.

Por ejemplo:

```
int n = 1; 
int numero[n];
```

Si tu compilas ese código en Visual Studio, te dará un error de compilación, puesto el compilador `cl.exe`(compilador de C/C++) obliga que el tamaño del arreglo sea una expresión constante (un número que se conoce en tiempo de compilación). ¿Por qué este compilador no me permite usar VLA? Pues la razón más evidente (supongo que habrá otros motivos) es por el problema del desbordamiento de pila. Como el arreglo `numero` está alojado en la pila, hay más probabilidades que ocurra un stack overflow, esto ocasionaría que el programa se detenga al instante.

La forma correcta sería usando `realloc`, con esta función podrás redimensionar el arreglo.

Su prototipo es: `void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);`

- `void* ptr`: Recibe la dirección base del arreglo.
- `size_t size`: Recibe el tamaño (en bytes) del arreglo.

Modo de uso:

```
int main()
{
    int* p = NULL;
    int* aux;
    aux = p;
    p = realloc(p, 5 * sizeof(int));
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        free(aux);
        printf("Error en la asignacion de memoria\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Se necesita de un puntero auxiliar para guardar la dirección de memoria que tenga almacenada `p`, puesto, que si llega a ver un fallo en la asignación de memoria (el puntero `p` será igual a `NULL`), puedas liberar la memoria, de lo contrario, habrá memory leak.

Debo recalcar que en ese ejemplo, `realloc` actuará como `malloc`, porqué se le está pasando al primer parámetro de la función `realloc` un `NULL`.

Hay varios casos que se debe detectar al momento de pedir el dato al usuario en tu problema planteado:

- Que el usuario no pueda ingresar un número entero + un caracter (por ejemplo: `232ffff`).
- Que el usuario no pueda ingresar cadenas (por ejemplo: `Hola Mundo`).
- Que el usuario no pueda ingresar la letra `x` + un caracter (por ejemplo: `xholaMundo`).

Con esta validación, obligas al usuario que solo pueda ingresar un número entero o la letra `x` o `X`.

Para lograr crear este algoritmo, necesitas saber que caracteres hay en el búfer del teclado y de ese modo, hacer las diversas comparaciones.

La función `getchar` es una subrutina que te permitirá tener acceso al búfer del teclado, ya que, lee un caracter a la vez de ese búfer.

Ahora, podemos crear una función que pida el número al usuario y que también valide si el dato es un número entero o una letra X.

```
/*
  Esta función retorna 1 si lo que ingresó el usuario 
no es un número o una letra X, de lo contrario, devuelve 0.
*/
int PedirNumero(int* numero, int* opSalir)
{
    int ch;
    printf("Ingrese un elemento:\n");

    //Si el usuario no ingresó un número..
    if(!scanf("%d", numero))
    {
        ch = getchar();
        //Si el usuario ingresó más de un caracter..
        if(getchar() != '\n')
        {
            //Limpia el búfer del teclado.
            while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
            return 1;
        }
        //Si el primer caracter no coincide con la x, X
        if(ch != 'x' && ch != 'X')
            return 1;
        *opSalir = ch;
    }
    else //De lo contrario, el usuario ingresó únicamene números ..
    {
        //Sin embargo, hay que detectar si en realidad lo hizo..
        if(getchar() != '\n')
        {
            //Limpia el búfer del teclado.
            while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Date cuenta que es necesario limpiar el búfer del teclado cada vez que haya un error, porque si no lo haces, cuando vuelvas a pedir otra vez el número, la función `scanf` no se detendrá y si esta subrutina está en un bucle, habrá un ciclo infinito.

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa: `x XXXx`. La función `scanf` retornará 0 porqué hubo un error y por lo tanto esta condición se cumple:

```
if(!scanf("%d", numero))
```

Luego se ejecuta esta línea:

```
ch = getchar();
```

En la variable `ch` tendremos la letra `x` (porqué es la primera letra de lo que ingresó el usuario).

Luego esta condición se cumplirá:

```
if(getchar() != '\n')
```

Porqué la función getchar leerá el siguiente caracter que sería un espacio y será diferente al salto de línea, con esta restricción detectamos si el usuario ingresó más de un caracter, aunque haya escrito primero la `x`. Como la condición se cumplió, el búfer del teclado se quedó con: `XXXx`(el espacio ya no queda, porqué el getchar anterior lo eliminó).

Entonces, si no limpiamos el búfer, cuando pidas de nuevo el dato, ahí tendrás problemas y de seguro será un bucle infinito (en nuestro caso sí).

El modo de uso de la función PedirNumero sería:

```
int main() 
{
    int n = 0; //tamaño del arreglo
    int* array = NULL; //un puntero que apunta a la dirección base del arreglo
    int* aux; //para guardar la dirección del puntero "array" y asi evitar pérdida de memoria.
    int numero = 0; //elemento ingresado por el usuario
    int opSalir = 0; //variable que guarda "x" o un cero.

    //Mientras el usuario ingrese cualquier número, menos la "x", se agrega ese número al arreglo
    while(1)
    {
        if(PedirNumero(&numero, &opSalir))
        {
            printf("Error: Solo se permite ingresar un numero entero o la letra x/X para salir del programa\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(opSalir == 'x' || opSalir == 'X') break;
        n++;
        aux = array;
        array = realloc(array, n * sizeof *array);
        if(array == NULL)
        {
            free(aux);
            printf("Error en la asignacion de memoria\n");
            return 1;
        }
        array[n - 1] = numero;
    }
  //El resto del código es el mismo que tenías antes...
```

En tu código original eliminé la función `agregarElementos` me pareció innecesario y también te faltó colocar el especificador de formato `%d` en este código:

```
printf("max: ", mayor); //%d
printf("pos: ", posMayor); //%d
printf("sum:", sum);//%d
```

De lo contrario, no te imprimirá el mayor, ni la posición, ni la suma.